# create a new class object on the fly using a foreach loop and the DirectoryIterator functions

Tags: php

I have a class that parses XML documents into an array.

I have 2 XML documents I want to parse and want to create a new class object on the fly using a foreach loop and the DirectoryIterator functions.

so far this is my attemp:

```
$settingsIterator = new DirectoryIterator(SETTINGS_PATH);

foreach ($settingsIterator as $fileInfo) {

    if ($fileInfo->isFile()) {

        $xmlFileObjName = strtolower(str_replace(".xml", "", $fileInfo->getFilename()));
        ${$xmlFileObjName} = new XML();
        ${$xmlFileObjName}->loadXML(SETTINGS_PATH . $fileInfo->getFilename());
    }
}
```

but of course this won't work. Is there a method to accomplish something like this?

My end goal is to have my script on execution iterate through my settings folder and create new XML object from each xml file in the directory.

Comment: Is there a special reason that the new object must be held in a variable with the same name as the file? If yes you are looking for variable variables: $$xmlFileObjName = new ....

Comment: yup, because i don't know what the variable will be called. I decided to give it the name of what ever the xml file being parsed will be. So if I have a language.xml file then it would look like `$language = new XML();` and I did already try to do a `$$` before posting here.

Comment: What's wrong with $xmlFile = new XML (); $xmlFile->loadXML ... ? It looks like you are complicating things for no reason :)

Comment: Ture, but it's an automated process I want to go thru. So i can add as many XML files to my dir and have it accessible on the fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to access these XML objects later, better idea is to stroe them in associative array:

```
$xmlObjects = array();
$xmlObjects[$xmlFileObjName] = new XML();
```